# travel london from Paris on schengen visa

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, sri-lankan-citizens

I am a Sri Lankan and I work in Israel. I will be applying for schenegan visa from Israel. I would like to know is it possible by Schengen visa to travel by Eurostar to London from Paris? Do I need uk visit visa also?

Answer (score 8):

The UK is not part of Schengen, so yes, you need a UK visa https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/sri-lanka/tourism/no